# How to "clear" data context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, datacontext

Some my script updates local data from external resources, get part of data, update and then get next part of data... my update code is:

```
    public void UpdateDrivers(List<Domain.POCO.Vistracks.VistrackDriverInfoDomain> list)
    {
        foreach (var model in list)
        {
            var driver = (from i in _db.Drivers
                          where i.AspNetUser.UserName.Equals(model.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                          select i).FirstOrDefault();

            driver = mapper.Map<VistrackDriverInfoDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.Driver>(model, driver);
            driver.IsVistracksAdded = true;
            driver.VistracksDateSync = DateTime.Now;
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

ok, it works if data is valid. Sometimes data can be invalid and it throws exception. I need to pass this part of data and try with the next. But when I try with the next part of data (valid data) it throws the same exception again.
I try to clear unchanged records by the following way:

```
_db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList().Clear();
```

but it does not help. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it the following way:

```
var changes = _db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
foreach (var entity in changes)
{
     _db.Entry(entity.Entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```